# How can I create a timer that will start at a certain time and wont interupt my program in pygame?

Tags: python, timer, pygame, render

I am making this game where you use the w, a, s, d keys to move a ball. I am trying to make a timer that starts when you press "start game". The problem is, when I do something like `time.sleep`, it interrupts the movement of the ball. I want to render the timer in the top right corner of the screen and make it 1 minute (also I will make a conditional statement for when the timer stops so I would like that to be possible).

Comment: Never sleep threads in an app unless you own the thread you're sleeping. PyGame probably has their own delay mechanism.

Comment: Create a variable `time = 0` and in the main loop do `dt += clock.tick(fps)` and `if start_game: time += dt`, where clock is a pygame.time.Clock() and fps is your frame-rate. The have an if-statement checking `if time >= 60000: start_game = False` (time will be in milliseconds).

Comment: Bonus info: you can combine these techniques with modulo to make something that happen every certain amount of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I believe would be easiest, and fit your needs the best.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60  # Or whatever frame-rate you want to cap the game at.
time = 0
game_started = False

# This is the main loop.
while True:

    dt = clock.tick(fps)

    if game_started:
        time += dt
    if time >= 60000:  # 60 seconds.
        game_started = False

    # Then handle, events, update/draw objects etc.
```

Just set `game_started = True` when you press the button and the `time` variable will start to increment in time. Then you can just draw the `time` variable to the screen however you like. If you don't want to draw it when it isn't running then just blit it when `game_started` is True.